# Get idToken using Paypal REST API

Tags: java, api, rest, paypal, token

I am building a REST API to login to my system using PayPal credentials.
I'd like to use the PayPal-Java-SDK and I've succeeded to get all the info I need for a given PayPal account (starting from the Auth Token).

I had a look at Paypal Spring Social and I found another token I wasn't considering in my implementation. It's called IdToken. For example [here](https://github.com/paypal/spring-social-paypal-openidconnect/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/social/openidconnect/support/OpenIdConnection.java)

I tried to search online, but I couldn't find much info about it.
Why is that token needed?
Is there a way to retrieve it using the REST API?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I misunderstand the SDK. It doesn't seem to be currently supporting OpenId. That's why I couldn't retrieve the IdToken with it.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, Java rest sdk for github should be supporting openID since it is a [supported REST API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#identity). Have you found that not to be the case?